Prevent Visual Studio from adding a BOM when transforming files
I have a JSON file someconfig.json along with Debug/Release transforms files someconfig.Debug/Release.json.
All three are encoded in UTF-8 without BOM.
But the files resulting from the transforms are encoded in UTF-8 with BOM.
How to preserve the original files encoding?

To save a file without BOM:

Select "Save As" in the file dialog.
Extend the save button options and choose "Save with encoding."
To change the default encoding permanently:

or

Open the "File" menu.
Select "Advanced Save Options."
Choose "UTF-8 without signature" (this is equivalent to "UTF-8
without BOM").

Note: "UTF-8 without signature" is the same as "UTF-8 without BOM."
refer to :
UTF-8 without BOM
And   Some methods allow for customization, such as the File.WriteAllText method:
File.WriteAllText("output.json", transformedContent, new UTF8Encoding(false));
When the variable is set to false, BOM will not be included.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.-ctor?view=net-8.0

Thanks, this is OK for the input files referenced by the projects in the VS solution. But the output files resulting from their transforms do not have the same encoding (BOM added).

Try use "new UTF8Encoding(false)" to explicitly specify UTF-8 encoding without BOM in all parts of your transformation code.

Thanks but I have no control over the code that generates the output, as it is implemented in Visual Studio (or maybe MSBuild or another build component).
